# No muestra correctamente el contenido del fichero dependiendo de la palabra

Tags: c, string, codeblocks, archivo

básicamente lo que tengo que hacer es que en un fichero tengo almacenado 3 frases y que dependiendo de la palabra que meta el usuario ejemplo "esquiar" me imprima por pantalla la frase entera que contiene esquiar. He hecho varias funciones para separar las cadenas e ir comparando carácter a carácter y luego dependiendo de si son iguales me devuelva un true y imprima, pero por alguna razón no me lo hace y me muestra todo el contenido del fichero. Y el compilador tampoco me avisa de ningún error en concreto, acabo de empezar ficheros así que no lo domino del todo. Os muestro mi código, aunque hay código que se tiene que hacer de esa manera porque el profesor lo dicta así:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *f;
    char cadenaBuscar[MAXCADENA];

    if(argc!=3) printf("ERROR: Tienen que ser 3 parámetros");
    else{
        strcpy(cadenaBuscar,argv[2]);
            printf("\nNombre del fichero %s\n\n",argv[1]);
            f=fopen(argv[1],"rt");
            if(f==NULL) printf("No se ha podido abrir el fichero");
            else{
                buscarPalabraFichero(cadenaBuscar,f);
                fclose(f);
            }
    }
    return 0;
}

void buscarPalabraFichero(char cadenaBuscar[MAXCADENA],FILE *f)
{
    char frase[MAXCADENA];
    char cadenaMostrar[MAXCADENA];

    fgets(cadenaMostrar,MAXCADENA,f);
    while(feof(f)==0){
        separarPorPalabras(cadenaMostrar,cadenaBuscar);
        fgets(cadenaMostrar,MAXCADENA,f);
    }
}

void separarPorPalabras(char cadenaMostrar[MAXCADENA],char cadenaBuscar[MAXCADENA]){
    int i = 0;
    char palabraAux[MAXCADENA];
    while(cadenaMostrar[i]!='\0' && i<MAXCADENA){
        obtenerPalabra(cadenaMostrar,&i,cadenaBuscar,palabraAux);
        i++;
    }
    if(comparacion(palabraAux,cadenaBuscar)){
        printf("%s",palabraAux);
    }else{
        printf("No se ha encontrado la palabra");
    }
}

void obtenerPalabra(char cadenaMostrar[MAXCADENA],int *i,char cadenaBuscar[MAXCADENA],char       palabraAux[MAXCADENA]){
    int j=0;
    while(esLetra(cadenaMostrar[*i])==0 && cadenaMostrar[*i]!='\0' && (*i)<MAXCADENA) (*i)++;

    while(esLetra(cadenaMostrar[*i]) && cadenaMostrar[*i]!='\0' && (*i)<MAXCADENA){
        if(cadenaMostrar[*i]==cadenaBuscar[j]){
            strcpy(palabraAux,cadenaMostrar);
        }
        (*i)++;
        j++;
    }
}

bool comparacion (char palabraAux[MAXCADENA],char cadenaBuscar[MAXCADENA]){
    bool encontrado=false;

    if(strcmpi(palabraAux,cadenaBuscar)){
        encontrado=true;
    }
    return encontrado;
}

bool esLetra(char c){
    char letras[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÀÁÈÉÍÏÒÓÚÜÑÇ";
    c=toupper(c);
    int i =0;
    bool encontrado = false;
    while(letras[i]!='\0' && !encontrado){
        if(letras[i]==c){
            encontrado = true;
        }else{
            i++;
        }
    }
    return encontrado;
}
```

Comment: Hay una función que se llama `strstr` que busca una cadena dentro de otra y te retorna el puntero a la posición donde la encontró o NULL si no la encontró. Con eso te sobra la gran mayoría de tu código.

Comment: Ya, pero por desgracia no nos dejan hacerlo desde esa forma

Comment: estaría bien que indicases qué código tiene que quedar tal cual ...

Comment: Pues por ejemplo la función obtenerPalabra sus instrucciónes no se pueden cambiar , pero el contenido si y lo mismo con separarPorPalabra el while tambien. El resto se puede modificar

Comment: @Wail ¿Por qué no te dejan usar `strstr`?

Comment: No nos han dado un motivo tal cual, pero como que quieren ver como se hace sin depender de esta función y si la usamos no nos validan el ejercicio.

Comment: @Wail Pues si no te dejan usar funciones estandares de C, pues te toca hacer las tuyas. Por ejemplo, [aqui](https://gist.github.com/MrDave1999/bbb5aa4afb5162fc46fb1d32742b315f) tienes una funcion que busca una subcadena dentro de una cadena..

Comment: Los profesores prohibiendo el uso de determinadas funciones en ejercicios denotan gran falta de imaginación a la hora diseñar ejercicios. No se puede enseñar a programar prohibiendo programar.